# Symbol identification problem

Tags: fonts, symbols, enumerate

How do I create an enumeration style like in the picture below (I mean things that look like concave `{` and `}`)?

[image: Example picture]

The Comprehensive Symbol List doesn't seem to know anything about those symbols. Googling didn't yield any useful results as well. I'm starting to suspect these symbols to be user-defined in some way.

Comment: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) gives me `\textlquill` and `\textrquill` from the `textcomp` package. So I guess, they are called “Quills”. The Comprehensive Symbol List lists them under [Table 162, p. 57](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf#page=57). Unicode has some similar characters: [⁅](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2045/index.htm) and [⁆](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2046/index.htm)

Comment: Is your problem finding the symbol (like your title and final paragraph suggests), or about implementing the type of "bracketed numbering" enumeration (like your first paragraph suggests)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an implementation, though I don't think those glyphs are particularly attractive or meaningful. For the text, I simply took three paragraphs from the http://ru.wikipedia.org home page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{textcomp,enumitem}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just for this example

\newlist{quills}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[quills,1]{
   label=\textlquill\roman*\textrquill,
   ref=\roman*,
   align=left,
   leftmargin=0pt,
   labelsep=0.33333em,
   labelwidth=!,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{quills}

\item История Византия охватывает период от основания города в VII
веке до н. э. до 330 года, когда римский император Константин I
Великий перенёс в Византий столицу своей империи.

\item С древнейших времён Босфор был стратегически важной торговой
артерией, и контроль его берегов сулил преимущество над конкурентами
во всей черноморской торговле. Основанный в середине VII века до
н. э. мегарскими колонистами, Византий благодаря своему выгодному
местоположению быстро превратился в важный торговый центр античного
мира.

\item Значительно пострадав во время греко-персидских войн, в
дальнейшем Византий стал ареной острой борьбы между Афинами и Спартой,
несколько раз переходя из рук в руки этих могущественных держав. С
ростом значения торговли в экономике Византия роль землевладельческой
аристократии уменьшалась, а демократически настроенная прослойка
купцов и мореходов, напротив, укрепляла свои позиции.

\end{quills}
\end{document}
```

[image]